# linux - sound from different apps going to different speakers?

Tags: linux, audio

My computer has a headphone jack on the front and back of it that have the same output.  Is it possible to have music going to the front headphone jacks and white noise sound going to speakers from the back jack?

The "Sound Preferences" option says I have two outputs - Internal Audio Output and a HDMI output.   So I guess the HDMI output could go to my monitor speakers for the white noise.

Answer (score 0):

The "HDMI output" option is for audio over the HDMI (or DVI-D) output. The front and back audio outputs are usually duplicated by hardware and can't be controlled independently by software, so I doubt that you can achieve this without an additional sound card.